# Golang Cobra command flags in common function not getting values from cli

Tags: go, command-line-interface, go-cobra, cobra

I'm moving my cobra command `flags` inside a function so I can use it in other commands. I can able to see the commands but when I type the flage it always returns `false`.

Following is my code:

```golang
func NewCommand(ctx context.Context) *cobra.Command {
    var opts ListOptions

    cmd := &cobra.Command{
        Use:   "list",
        Short: "List",
        RunE: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) error {
            fmt.Println(args) // []
            opts.refs = args
            return List(ctx, gh, opts, os.Stdout)
        },
    }

    cmd = GetCommandFlags(cmd, opts)
    return cmd
}

// GetListCommandFlags for list
func GetCommandFlags(cmd *cobra.Command, opts ListOptions) *cobra.Command {
    flags := cmd.Flags()
    flags.BoolVar(&opts.IgnoreLatest, "ignore-latest", false, "Do not display latest")
    flags.BoolVar(&opts.IgnoreOld, "ignore-old", false, "Do not display old data")
    return cmd
}
```

So when I type the following command

```
data-check list --ignore-latest
```

The the flag value of `--ignore-latest` should be `true` but I get `false` as a value in `RunE` args. Am I missing something here?

`GetCommandFlags` is something I want to use it in other commands I don't want to repeat the same flags.

Comment: func `GetCommandFlags` has two parameteres but you are passing three.

Comment: So just edited from a big code for a simpler view and missed it. Update the code again.  @MasudurRahman

Comment: I added an answer which works for me. You can check that.

Comment: Yup. I missed the import thing while debugging.. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `func GetCommandFlags(cmd *cobra.Command, opts *ListOptions)` and call the func like `cmd = GetCommandFlags(cmd, &opts)`.

You can print `opts.IgnoreLatest` and `opts.IgnoreOld` to see the changed value.

Works fine for me. Hope it will work for you too.

```golang
func NewCommand(ctx context.Context) *cobra.Command {
    var opts ListOptions

    cmd := &cobra.Command{
        Use:   "list",
        Short: "List",
        RunE: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) error {
            // fmt.Println(args) // []
            fmt.Println(opts.IgnoreLatest, ", ", opts.IgnoreOld)
            opts.refs = args
            return List(ctx, gh, opts, os.Stdout)
        },
    }

    cmd = GetCommandFlags(cmd, &opts)
    return cmd
}

// GetListCommandFlags for list
func GetCommandFlags(cmd *cobra.Command, opts *ListOptions) *cobra.Command {
    flags := cmd.Flags()
    flags.BoolVar(&opts.IgnoreLatest, "ignore-latest", false, "Do not display latest")
    flags.BoolVar(&opts.IgnoreOld, "ignore-old", false, "Do not display old data")
    return cmd
}
```

Comment: Yup!!!! I tried them before `*ListOptions` `&opts` but I tried printing the `args` too bad of me... It works perfectly... Thanks for ur help @Masudur

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `opts` to `GetCommandFlags` by value. You should pass a pointer to it, so the addresses registered for the flags use the `opts` declared in the calling function.

```
func GetCommandFlags(cmd *cobra.Command, opts *ListOptions) *cobra.Command {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry I tried it already and it's not working I get the `args` as empty still.

Comment: You will not get ignore-latest as an argument. It is registered as a flag, so you will get it from the `opts.IgnoreLatest`. Arguments are not flags, you use them for things like `data-list list 10`, where `list` is a command and `10` is an argument to that command. You have to declare that the command expects 1 argument, and after that, your `args` will contain one element in it, which is "10".

Comment: But what if I decided to not use any flags which In command. I cant use `Expects 1 argument` here :(

Comment: I do not understand this statement. In your example, `--ignore-latest` is a flag, not an argument to a command.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing value parameter not a pointer parameter.

Try someting like:

```
cmd = GetCommandFlags(cmd, &opts, "")
```

Comment: So just edited from a big code for a simpler view and missed it. Update the code again.  @heat